# Alternative to stackengine for inline, bracketed text

Tags: formatting

I am not sure why I need to go into math mode to accomplish inline, bracketed, stacked text. Are there other options that I am missing?

[image: example: inline, bracketed text]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

La lettre représentative
$\left\{\Centerstack[l]{{d’un point} {d’une droite}}\right\},$
mise entre

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: stretchy {} are a math mode feature so any solution witll use math mode internally, although of course it could be hidden so you do not explicitly use math mode markup in the document. you could of course use tabular for the central part you don't need any package here.

Comment: I agree with David.  Your title maligns `stackengine`, when the issue is not `stackengine` (which stacks in text mode by default), but the need for stretchable braces in text mode.

Comment: As far as I know, *droite* is feminine, so *d’une droite*.

Comment: @egreg much appreciated!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I hope it wasn't so much my title which maligned `stackengine` as the opening line of my question. I have edited said line. No offense intended.

Comment: None taken.  I can get a bit prickly over my baby.  Just ignore me.

Comment: And, as Oscar Wilde once noted, "the only thing worse than being talked about...is not being talked about!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is something you use often, just absorb it into a macro definition.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\textstack[1]{$\left\{\Centerstack[l]{#1}\right\}$}
\begin{document}

La lettre représentative
\textstack{d’un point\\d’un droite},
mise entre

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `delarray` to avoid explicit math markup, although any solution using stretchy delimiters will be using math internally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}


La lettre représentative
\begin{tabular}\{{@{}l@{}}\}d’un point\\d’un droite\end{tabular},
mise entre


\end{document}
```